# Implementing sequelize ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sails.js, sequelize.js

I am implementing sequelizer in an sailsJS application (ExpressJs), I am following this tutorial: 
https://github.com/sequelize/express-example from the sequelize team that explain how to implement it. But I still getting an error, my only model by the moment is (The same of the repository):

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  });

return User;
};
```

And here is where I'm trying to create a new object:

```
var models = require("../api/models");
  models.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  models.User.create({
    username: "MiguelCrespo"
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("THEN");
  });
});
```

And after trying that I get this error:

[image: Error]

But I can search in the models correctly, this error is only when I try to save or create a new object in the database